# Neural Network - Basic Python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I am using the following tutorial for developing a basic neural network that does feedforward and backdrop. The link to the tutorial is here : [Python Neural Network Tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-your-own-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-68998a08e4f6)

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0/(1+ np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return x * (1.0 - x)

class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.input      = x
        self.weights1   = np.random.rand(self.input.shape[1],4) 
        self.weights2   = np.random.rand(4,1)                 
        self.y          = y
        self.output     = np.zeros(self.y.shape)

    def feedforward(self):
        self.layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.input, self.weights1))
        self.output = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer1, self.weights2))

    def backprop(self):
        # application of the chain rule to find derivative of the loss function with respect to weights2 and weights1
        d_weights2 = np.dot(self.layer1.T, (2*(self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output)))
        d_weights1 = np.dot(self.input.T,  (np.dot(2*(self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output), self.weights2.T) * sigmoid_derivative(self.layer1)))

        # update the weights with the derivative (slope) of the loss function
        self.weights1 += d_weights1
        self.weights2 += d_weights2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    X = np.array([[0,0,1],
                  [0,1,1],
                  [1,0,1],
                  [1,1,1]])
    y = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])
    nn = NeuralNetwork(X,y)

    for i in range(1500):
        nn.feedforward()
        nn.backprop()

    print(nn.output)
```

What im trying to do is change the data set and return 1 if the predicted number is even and 0 if the same is odd. So I made the following changes :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    X = np.array([[2,4,6,8,10],
                  [1,3,5,7,9],
                  [11,13,15,17,19],
                  [22,24,26,28,30]])
    y = np.array([[1],[0],[0],[1]])
    nn = NeuralNetwork(X,y)

The output I get is :
[[0.50000001]
 [0.50000002]
 [0.50000001]
 [0.50000001]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: With the way the weighting and everything is setup you probably need to normalize the data X before running nn on it

Comment: Check your sigmoid_derivative function, consider replacing `x` with `sigmoid(x)` in both places.

Comment: @GustavRasmussen How do I normalise the data? Im sorry, Im super new to ML just started infact.

Comment: @AbbeGijly Ok, let me try that out, but could you explain why?

Comment: Look up the equation for the derivative of `sigma(x)` -- you'll see it has `sigma(x)` terms in it, vs. `x` alone.  (I noticed it because the derivative expression seemed too simple)  Check out this page:  https://towardsdatascience.com/derivative-of-the-sigmoid-function-536880cf918e  skip everything and just jump to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are two problems here:

1. Your expression of sigmoid_derivative is wrong, it should be:

   return sigmoid(x)*((1.0 - sigmoid(x)))
2. If you take a look at the sigmoid function plot or your network weights, you would find out that your network saturated due to your large input. By doing something like X=X%5 you can get the training result you want, as the result of mine on your data:

   [[9.99626174e-01]
    [3.55126310e-04]
    [3.55126310e-04]
    [9.99626174e-01]]

[image: sigmoid plot]

Comment: This change gives me the following errors : /Applications/AMPPS/www/Machine Learning/lab1.py:4: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  return 1.0/(1+ np.exp(-x)) and the output is still 0.5

Comment: You may need to modify your sigmoid derivative according to my first suggestion

Comment: By modifying the sigmoid derivative function as per your suggestion, im getting the above mentioned error and the result as 0.5 consistently.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It'd be X=X%5 instead of X=X/5, as this will rescale your input into the interval of [0,4], which has the largest slope available for gradient descent.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `X = X/30` and train the network 10 times longer. This converged for me. You divide `X` by 30 to make every input in between 0 and 1. You train it longer because it is a more complex dataset.

Your derivative is fine because when you use the derivative function, the input to it is already `sigmoid(x)`. So `x*(1-x)` *is* `sigmoid(x)*(1-sigmoid(x))`